# How to setup a graylog instance as a proxy?

Tags: logging, graylog

How to setup a graylog instance as a proxy?

Is it possible to set up a second graylog instance, which is to be configured as a proxy? This instance should collect the data from devices in one network and forward it to the graylog master server in another network.

Is this possible with Graylog, and if so how?